# "void value not ignored as it ought to be" error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, void

I am getting an error "void value not ignored as it ought to be" on the line:

`home = [[Home alloc] initWithPhoto:imageView.image];`

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Home class' `-initWithPhoto:` function is probably returning void. Initializer functions are supposed to return `id`.

Answer (score 2):

What is the return value of `initWithPhoto`? The error means that the method is returning `void` but you are assigning that to something. `initWithPhoto` should look something like this:

```
- (id)initWithPhoto:(UIImage *)image {
    if (self = [super init]) {
         // do your tasks
    }

    return self;
}
```

The method should return `id`, not `void`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `initWithPhoto` method is returning an object of type `void` when it should be returning an object of type `id`, especially if you're expecting the `home` variable to contain anything useful. Try editing the `initWithPhoto` method to return an object of type `id`.